# How to link to specify section of a HTML page as: <div id="here"></div>?

Tags: php, html

I have an UL and I need to link those images to the right section of projects.php: EG:ProjectA.jpg to link >> projects.php `<section id="projectA"</section>`

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a title="View project" href="projects.php">
      <img alt="" src="ProjectA.jpg" />
      <figcaption>BLABLA</figcaption>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a title="View project" href="projects.php">
      <img alt="" src=".jpg" />
      <figcaption>BLABLA</figcaption>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<!--end ul-->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<a href="projects.php#projectA">your link</a>`

Comment: You are right! I was using a slash `<a href="projects.php/#projectA">your link</a>` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To link like you want, simply add `#sectionname` to your anchor href. So in your example:

```
<a title="View project" href="projects.php#projectA"> 
    <img alt="" src="ProjectA.jpg"/>
    <figcaption>BLABLA</figcaption> 
</a>
```